# PHP file_get_contents: Get caller info

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using file_get_contents(http://example.com/mypage.php)

Is there a way to get info from caller (ie: $_SERVER variable or hostname) from the web site who call the page ?

David

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream_context_create() to set options that get passed into file_get_contents() to create a custom user-agent and host header that would be sent along with the request.

Haven't tried it, but something like so should work.

```
<?php
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'header'=>"Host: www.mycallingserver.com",
        'user_agent'=>"My Custom User Agent"
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

David, your question doesn't make any sense to me.

What does file_get_contents have to do with obtaining $_SERVER variable information? file_get_contents reads a file/uri and returns a text stream. Has nothing to do with obtaining $_SERVER variable information.

If you are writing a PHP script, you are the caller. You can get $_SERVER variable information on the server you are running the script on, but not from the other websites. That would be a security issue.

Comment: You're a bit right. From the PHP script on server-A, I call file_get_contents('http://server-B.com/mypage.php'). I was only wondering if I can get server-A information like hostname from server-B without sending those info.

Comment: file_get_contents(server-B.com/mypage.php) doesn't get the executed results of mypage.php. It returns just the PHP file itself as text.